# Unity with Visual Studio: Is "go to declaration" possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, go-to-definition

Is it possible to set up Visual Studio (Community 2015) so that "Go to Definition" behaves as "Go to Declaration" for C# classes provided by the Unity Engine?

I don't want to use MonoDevelop ...

Comment: Most of the declarations are already compiled so you can't "Go to Declaration" on many of them in VStudio (2013, I haven't tested w/ 2015).  However, you can go to Definition with shortcuts (though I know that's not what you want).  Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn940020(v=VS.140).aspx

Comment: Well, since MonoDevelop can access some classes (like Mathf), there must be some source attachment available, right?

Comment: Right, which is why I said "most declarations."  Some work and some do not.  Not totally sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Like what Max von Hippel said, since the declarations are already compiled, there's no way to use Go to Declaration.

The only alternative that I can suggest to you is to use Shift+F12 when your text cursor is on the method name. This will bring up "Find Symbol Results" tab somewhere in Visual Studio (works for 2008, 2010, 2012, and 2015). If you double-click on the result you are looking for, it will automatically jump to where the method is called on, or rather, "referenced at".